# Pandas Dataframe.to_csv causing issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am calling python file from java

```
def solve_......(Client_ID,data_folder):
    g = open('.........\\'+str(Client_ID)+'\\'+str(data_folder)+'\data_load.log', 'a+')

    f= open('...........\\'+str(Client_ID)+'\\'+str(data_folder)+'\conversion\csv\\bom.csv', 'rU')
    readfile = csv.reader(f)
    bom = [tuple(line) for line in readfile]

    Input_Data_df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(bom), columns = ['Material', 'BOM Component', 'Attach Rate', 'Yield', 'Alt. BOM', 'Alternative Item Grp', 'Alternative Priority', 'Usage Probability %', 'Validate From'])
    Input_Data_df1['Deletion Flag'] = '0'


    Filtered_Data = Input_Data_with_alt_bom_count.drop(Input_Data_with_alt_bom_count[(Input_Data_with_alt_bom_count["Material"] == i) & (Input_Data_with_alt_bom_count["Alt. BOM"] != 1)].index)
    pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

    SP_BOM_Format = Filtered_Data
    SP_BOM_Format['Valid To'] = '31.12.9999'  ## Added new column 'Valid To' as is not there in Halonix SAP format

    required_columns = ['Material', 'BOM Component', 'Attach Rate', 'Yield','Validate From', 'Valid To', 'Deletion Flag']
    g.write('777' + "\n")
    print 11111111    
    SP_BOM_Format.to_csv(r'E:\BitBucket\WildFly11.0.0\standalone\dataload\loadedfiles\\'+str(Client_ID)+'\\'+str(data_folder)+'\csv\\bom1.csv',index=False,header = True, columns = required_columns)
    print 2222222222
```

py file is running succesfully when i run from pycharm, but when i call py file from java the last statement SP_BOM_Format.to_csv is causing issue (No such file is found) where as am trying to place the file in that path and single backslash \ is printing as double \. Is there anything change in my statement

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Not sure how you're running it from `java`, but you can wrap the code in a python `try...catch` and print/log the potential exceptions.

Comment: @adrin actual question is edited now, Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what java has to do with this? Also, it's useful to mention which version of python and which OS.

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash (`/`) works as well in `python` under Windows. Replace your backstashes (`\`) with slashes. Also, always try to manage your paths using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html) method:

```
from os.path import join
variable = 'my folder'
join('e:', 'parent', 'child', variable, 'file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

import os
try os. path.join

```
try:
    outname = 'bom.csv'
    outdir = 'E:\BitBucket\WildFly11.0.0\standalone\dataload\loadedfiles\\'+str(Client_ID)+'\\'+str(data_folder)+'\csv'
    if not os.path.exists(outdir):
        os.mkdir(outdir)
    fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)
    print fullname
    SP_BOM_Format.to_csv(fullname)
except Exception as x:
    print x
```